# How to convert to boxplot from histogram in R or matlab?

Tags: r, matlab

I have have data in a histogram format but I'd like to make it into a boxplot using either R or matlab. Is it possible or do I need to work out Q1, Q2 and Q3 manually?

[image]

```
bin_extents bin_values
81.242  8
86.95   2283
92.658  13619
98.365  67042
104.07  1532
109.78  359
115.49  288
121.2   145
126.9   86
```

Comment: Due to the binning of the histogram, you can't calculate the exact quantiles from histogram data. You can only calculate an approximation and the precision depends on the breaks of the histogram.

Comment: OK, thank you. I might be able to get hold of the full data in another way.